# Sending email without intent

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to send an email[NO INTENT] from my application , but it does not send. Can maybe anyone tell me what wrong there is no error in LOGCAT.

```
final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend); 
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            public void onClick(View v) {         
           try 
         {    
            javamail sender = new javamail("MY EMAIL", "My Password" ); 
            sender.sendMail("HI",    
                    "I'm trying Androin Email :)",    
                    "Person I sent to",    
                    "djkgotsod@gmail.com");    
            Log.d("send", "Owk");
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);    
        }  

    } 
});
```

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that you are doing network I/O on the main application thread. At best, this is dangerous; at worst, Android will crash your app. Please move your network I/O to a background thread.

Comment: that what i saw in the example I was using..

Comment: @CommonsWare i have used example you have given but its not working for me.. does it needs any smtp or any other setting?? please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

What I do, is send the email to a php script using HTTP POST. Then my server sends the actual email using php's mail(). That way, you bypass a minefield of problems eg some carriers block port 25.

Comment: owk! I really dont know what to do that my new in android

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124) post, It uses JavaMail API with Gmail authenticator.
Note, You must type in a valid gmail user and password 
Hope this helps.

Comment: That what I used but...still i dont get tha results...my gmail is valid and password

Comment: void com.proapps.eng.android.client.GMailSender.sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception         try this: sender.sendMail("subject","body","The Sender Email!!!" , "the Recepient Email like djkgotsod@gmail.com");

Comment: Can you please paste your exception.. try wrap the whole thing with try catch maybe

Comment: what do you mean because everything is on try catch

Comment: Have you tried,as said before, to change the sender email in  sender.sendMail method?

Comment: cant you post that method u talking about

Comment: There u go.. this works perfect for me:  try {GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(cntx.getString(R.string.from_mail), cntx.getString(R.string.from_mail_pass));
sender.sendMail("Mail Sent from Customer "+name_text.getText().toString(), free_text.getText().toString()          + "\n\n\nPhone Number: "+ phone_text.getText().toString()+ "\nDate: "+ _date + "\nTime: " + _time, cntx           .getString(R.string.from_mail), cntx           .getString(R.string.customer_mail));} catch (Exception e) {Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);}